# Pagination and Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq

In my mobile app, I try to retrieve data from a table of my SQL Server database. I'm using EF and I try to use pagination for better performance. I need to retrieve data from the last element of the table. so if the table has 20 rows, I need, for page 0, IDs 20, 19, 18, 17, 16 then for page 1 IDs 15, 14, 13, 12, 11 and so on...

The problem is this: what if, while user "A" is downloading data from table, user "B" add row? If user "A" get Page 0 (so IDs 20, 19, 18, 17, 16), and user "B" in the same moment add row (so ID 21), with classic query, user "A" for page 1 will get IDs 16, 15, 14, 13, 12... so another time ID 16

My code is very simple:

```
int RecordsForPagination = 5; 
var list = _context.NameTable
                   .Where(my_condition)
                   .OrderByDescending(my_condition_for ordering)
                   .Skip (RecordsForPagination * Page)
                   .Take (RecordsForPagination)
                   .ToList();
```

Of course `Page` is int that come from the frontend.

How can I solve the problem?

I found a solution but I don't know if it's the perfect one. I could use

```
.SkipWhile(x => x.ID >= LastID)
```

instead

```
.Skip (RecordsForPagination * Page)
```

and of course `LastID` always is sent from the frontend.

Do you think that performance is always good with this code? Is there a better solution?

Comment: Pagination is a solution to a problem where users may query more data than might reasonably be displayed in one go. When the data is sorted properly it is expected that the users will predominantly be reviewing page 1. (As the saying goes, "The best place to hide a dead body is on Page 2 of the Google Search results.") If you really must display results as a "Point in time" then be sure to record CreatedAt with rows and capture the initial search with a `.Where(x => x.CreatedAt <= firstRunAt)` where firstRunAt is captured at search start. But that's really a solution in search of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The performance impacts will depend greatly on your SQL Index implementation and the order by clause. But its not so much a question about performance as it is about getting the expected results.

> Stack Overflow is a great example where there is a volume of activity such that when you get to the end of any page, the next page may contain records from the page you just viewed because the underlying recordset has changed (more posts have been added)
>
> I bring this up because in a live system it is generally accepted and in some cases an *expected* behaviour. As developers we appreciate the added overheads of trying to maintain a single result set and recognise that there is usually much lower value in trying to prevent what looks like *duplications* as you iterate the pages.
>
> It is often enough to explain to users why this occurs, in many cases they will accept it

If it was important to you to maintain the place in the original result set, then you should constrain the query with a `Where` clause, but you'll need to retrieve either the Id or the timestamp in the original query. In your case you are attempting to use `LastID`, but to get the last ID would require a separate query on it's own because the orderby clause will affect it.

You can't really use `.SkipWhile(x => x.ID >= LastID)` for this, because *skip* is a sequential process that is affected by the order and is dis-engaged the first instance that the expression evaluates to `false`, so if your order is not based on `Id`, your skip while might result is skipping no records at all.

```
int RecordsForPagination = 5; 
int? MaxId = null;
...
var query = _context.NameTable.Where(my_condition);
// We need the Id to constraint the original search
if (!MaxId.HasValue)
    MaxId = query.Max(x => x.ID);

var list = query.Where(x => x.ID <= MaxId)
                .OrderByDescending(my_condition_for ordering)
                .Skip(RecordsForPagination * Page)
                .Take(RecordsForPagination);
                .ToList();
```

It is generally simpler to filter by a point in time as this is known from the client without a round trip to the DB, but depending on the implementation the filtering on dates can be less efficient.

Comment: My intention was not to retrieve LastID from DB (because, as you said, this would be affected by Db itself). my intention was this:

- Frontend retrieve Page 0 and result are IDs 20, 19, 18, 17, 16
- Frontend retrieve Page 1 and pass to backend two param: Page 1 and LastID of previous Page (in this case LastID = 16) -> so result will be IDs 15, 14, 13, 12, 11... and so on.

my English is not perfect... are we saying the same thing?

Comment: @user1106897 The technique Chris refers to is called [Keyset Pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset), and is generally much better than paging by rows, which is what you are talking about

Comment: It very much *is* also a question of performance: paging by rows is highly inefficient as all previous rows need to be read every time. Whereas paging by key (or time in this case) is highly efficient if there is a supporting index

Comment: Charlie face thank you so much for the link, really appreciated. I’ll try to use advices

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface the performance remark was more supposed to be "forget the performance, SkipWhile(by id) will not solve the problem if you change the order" Great link too!